# Access specifier, not able to call a function which is defined in the derived class

Tags: c++, access-specifier

I tried to learn about the access specifier in c++, So i access a public and protected member from the base class and performed a add function in the derived class as shown below,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        int a;
    protected:
        int b;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        int sum;
        void add()
        {   
            a = 10;
            b = 20;
            sum = a + b;
        }
};


int main()
{
    Derived Obj;
    Obj.add;
    cout << "The sum : " << Obj.sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But while compile i get the following error message "statement cannot resolve address of the overload function" can anyone explain what is the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Obj.add;` supposed to mean? This is not a valid statement in C++. This is what the compiler is telling you. Functions in C++ are called through `()` operator. If you wanted to call a function, then where is your `()` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call is missing parenthesis in the following line:

```
Obj.add;
```

It should be: `Obj.add();`